# ¿Como puedo pedir datos de tipo numericos al usuario en flutter?

Tags: formularios, flutter, conversión-de-tipos, datos, textfield

Tengo este código:

```
class InputConversor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputConversorState createState() => _InputConversorState();
}

class _InputConversorState extends State<InputConversor> {
  int _metros = 0;
  //Creamos el conrtolador que sera utilizado apra reucperar el valor actual del TextFielc
//  TextEditingController myController;

  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        crearIngreso(),
        Text(myController.text),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget crearIngreso() {
    return TextField(
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
      controller: myController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Escribi tu valor en metros",
      ),
      onTap: () {},
      onChanged: (myController) {
        setState(
          () {
            myController;
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Limpia el controlador cuando el Widget se descarte
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Desopues arriba de esto tengo un stateless, donde lo añado a mi scaffold y todo eso.

Estoy iniciando en la progrmaación con flutter, hice un formulario sin estilo ni nada, le quiero pedir que me de un número, pero cuando lo escribe es de tipo string, quiero que sea un "int" entonces yo puedo hacer operaciones amtemáticas con ello.

Por ejemplo, si el usuario escribe el "10" quiero que devuelva abajo escrito "60" porque quiero hacer un codigo que el numero que ingrese el usuario le sume 50.

Es decir, el problema con que me encuentro es que no se como transformar ese string a numero o si hay que hacerlo de otra manera que no sea con un fomrulario.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la variable que deseas que fuese un int?

Comment: Puedes mostrar el scaffold?

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de transformar como dices de string a int es:

```
main () {
    var one = int.parse('1');
    print(one == 1); // prints true
}
```

Usas una variable, en este caso he llamado one, a la que asignas el parseo o transformación del número logrado.

Lo del print es para que observes que si te da true, es porque es un número y no un string.

Answer (score 0):

Tu textfield debe quedar asi:

```dart
    return TextField(
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
      controller: myController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Escribi tu valor en metros",
      ),
      onTap: () {},
      onChanged: (String value) {
        setState(
          () {
            _metros  = int.parse(value);
            print ('El valor de metros es: $_metros');
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Es importante que notes que `onChanged` recibe una funcion anonima que tiene como parametro un `String`. Este `String` lo debes convertir a `int` con la funcion `int.parse(value)`.